# Android R files from external libraries Intellij (not as jar!)

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I have a problem of being use resoure file from the external library on Intellij.
On runtime when I tried to get a view from resource from the external Library layout and its wrote "Class not loaded : packege_name.lib.R".

This problem goes only on runtime on Intellij when I call to Activity from the external library that I added it decleration on the main project manifest file.

Any help?

Thanks.